# how to undeploy a react web app from firebase hosting

Tags: create-react-app, firebase-hosting

I deployed a react web app on firebase a month ago, now i want to delete that how can i do so.I already deleted that from firebase and also tried "firebase hosting:disable" but not works.

Comment: It may be cached, have you tried using any other device?

Comment: i tried on at least 3devices, but works on all.